# irb does not use my .irbrc

Tags: ruby, rvm

On my MacOS, I have the default ruby, but for certain development task, I also have installed ruby 2.4.2 via rvm. When I explicitly invoke

```
/usr/bin/irb
```

my ~/.irbrc is processed (I verified it by putting a `puts :processing` at top of this file).

When I use the irb which rvm puts into my PATH (i.e. in my case `/Users/MYNAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.2/bin/irb`, the ~/.irbrc is not processed.

I also tried to explicitly do a

```
export IRBRC=$HOME/.irbrc
```

but this also did not help. What could be the reason?

BTW, in case it matters: I'm using zsh as interactive shell.

Comment: You’re referencing two different locations.  Which is correct?  `~/.irbc` or `~/.rvm`?

Comment: @Allab : `.rvm` happens to be a **directory** under which somewhere the Ruby binaries are stored. `.irbrc` is the **startup** file for `irb`. I don't see what one has to do with the other. From my understanding, the startup file is by default searched in the HOME directory, but this can be overridden by setting the environment variable `IRBRC`.

Comment: My mistake.  I misread the “rvm” line as having “irbc” at the end.  In that case I’d suggest  setting the env variable by expanding the `$HOME` in braces → `${HOME}/.irbc`. Also, it’d be interesting to see the output of `echo $IRBC` to see if it gets set somewhere else.

Comment: @Allan: Braces are not necessary here, because a / acts as terminator for a variable name. You can try it out for yourself: Just do a  `echo $HOME/foobar`.

Comment: I know how they work  It’s *safe* a technique to get a user to revisit the source rather than recall things from memory.  There’s a minor error in there and I’m sure it will jump out.  Notice how the second part of my comment was ignored?

Comment: @Allan: To add to this, I of course ensured that the variable has the right value. I actually invoked irb by the command `IRBRC=$HOME/.irbrc ..../irb` (the name of the variable is `IRBRC`, not `IRB`), to make sure that the value is correct. Since it works fine when I use `/usr/bin/irb` instead, the differences must be in the irb which I received via rvm. I'm already thinking to drop rvm (which does not work that well with zsh anyway) in favor of rbenv.

Comment: You have two versions of irb.  Why do you assume the global settings for each are identical?

Comment: I don't use any "global setting". My .irbrc contains startup code which works for all my Ruby versions (and I'm responsible for this). AFIK the rules of where to find the .irbrc have not changed  between the versions I happen to have here. If MRI irb  for Ruby 2.6 would search .irbrc according to a different process than MRI irb for Ruby 2.4, I would at least know the differences. If rvm would do some internal magic for specifying a different .irbrc for each managed version, I would then like to know WHERE the .irbrc is looked up. Then I can at least place there a symlink to my ~/.irbrc .

Comment: @Allan : Actually, I looked up the [rvm docs](https://rvm.io/workflow/irbrc) for the safe side, and that page clearly says that the .irbrc in my HOME is supposed to be processed always. Actually, it would be a pretty bizarre design, if they would chage this. If I really have version-dependent code inside my .irbrc, I will test the Ruby version explicitly using Ruby code inside this file.